# Simulating Circuits and Programming Micro-controllers over Linux

Tags: c, linux, compiler-construction, embedded, pic

I'm about to go through a Micro-Controller project which controls a robotic arm. My problem is that @ MS Windows there are MikroElectronica (IDE: MicroC) compile .c to Hex put the hex in Proteus and simulate. Then using a special (PCB) Kit with CD (carries windows software) I would put the microchip and install the hex file or what ever.

First all the respect to Ms but I just hate it! I adore Ubuntu/linux and open-source I need from the experts to tell me in "Steps" how to do the previously mentioned in linux with minimal complications.

The Electrical and Mechanical Engineers along with me always brag about Ms is easy. I want to show them how Computer Science guy uses open-source technology and how strong and reliable it is.

Please help !

Comment: are you looking for a specific microcontroller tool, etc or in general want to show that open source linux is as easy and sometimes easier than windows.  There are a number of places where open source will be much easier, sometimes not, but specific tools for specific libraries/rtos for a specific board, you might be locked into windows or the linux solution might be painful.

Comment: I believe the high-tech c compiler has a linux version, pretty sure they do as I used their arm tools before they were bought by microchip.  tons of pic users out there and a percentage are linux users.  There are likely many pic assemblers out there and pic simulators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wish to demonstrate the power of Linux by trying to run products designed for another operating system on it? Chances are those tools may work in [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/).

Or maybe you can use [Hi-Tech C](http://www.htsoft.com/) as a compiler and try [gEDA](http://www.gpleda.org) for simulation. It is also possible to compile [Microchip C30](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en023073) on Linux if you are working on 16-bit PIC:s. In any case, this may not be as easy as using the out-of the-box Windows tools. It will be more educational, nevertheless.

Comment: I prefer verilator to icarus verilog, but both are just fine.  Depending on the pic finding a pic clone in verilog or just creating your own is not that big of a task, it is a simple instruction set.  The peripherals will probably take more work than the core.  verilator makes it super easy to cross the hardware/software boundary and you can likely simulate the rest of the board/system that way.

Comment: so from your link, has microchip open sourced some of their tools?

Comment: @dwelch, yes, the "MPLAB C Compiler for PIC24 MCUs and dsPIC DSCs" is based on gcc, and the compiler source code is available. They haven't yet released their libc sources, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you can be flexible and opt for AVR then you will have free GCC compiler and programming tools. All open source and Linux/Mac friendly. More info at www.avrfreaks.com.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.micahcarrick.com/pic-programming-linux.html) is a compiler, linker and simulator tutorial for PIC on linux. [Here](http://hackaday.com/2010/11/03/how-to-program-pics-using-linux/) is one that uses SDCC c compiler. Google throws out lots of websites when you search for `linux pic`.

Answer (score 1):

From my side, I cross-compile and program Microchip dsPIC from Linux but it is not really straightforward. Here are the big steps

First I built the C30 toolchain from Microchip sources (you need to apply a few patches on the given sources for it to compile).
Once you have the toolchain binaries, you will need to have the specific Microchip MCU resources. Those are coming with the C30 installation on a win32. I copied those files from the Windows installation folder onto my linux filesystem.
Here you should be able to compile and link some C & ASM code to a hex file through command line.

Second step, I wanted to build my projects within the Eclipse IDE. To do that we "just" had to write a couple makefiles to call our new C30 toolchain.

Third step, program the .hex onto your microchip MCU. Two ways to do it. If you have a Pickit2, Microchip provides a command line tool to play with it. I personally have an ICD2 programmer. I use the command line tool provided in the Piklab project.

Now I don't have any facility to debug with my ICD2 under Linux.
Now Microchip provides an alternative IDE with "Mplab X" which is based on Netbeans (sick) and should work under Linux and MacOS. But this project seemed to be yet under development, I don't know if it is really usable.